# grpc c++ client does not support use dynamic table of http2 on the custom header

Tags: c++, grpc

I add a metadata to use custom header in grpc c++ client, and then to send some same requests to server. I catch the http data by tcpdump and parse it. It shows that the custom header not use index. My code is base on the example of cpp/helloworld/greeter_client.cc and add metadata code like this:

```
context.AddMetadata("abc-bin", "akjfsdkfalfafjljfaljfdlajkldajdklfajd");
```

the wireshark parse it and shows this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTFZn.png)

and the after requests is also not use index.

my grpc version is v1.60.0.

I read the source code and debug it. It looks like grpc not support custom header to use index represent it.

I want to make sure if it's really not supported or if I'm using it wrong。